# Select condicional que pega valor de outra tabela

Tags: mysql, query

Preciso fazer um select condicional que verifica uma soma realizada dessa forma:

```
select round(sum((`gin`.`Caixa_9L` / 1000)),1) AS `total` from `gin`
```

Se essa soma acima for = 0, preciso pegar um valor de um campo em uma outra tabela (chamada asterisco) e exibir como total.

Estou iniciando em sql e estou com um pouco de dificuldade pra definir essa lógica.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select case CAIXA_9L when ( round(sum((Caixa_9L / 1000)),1)  = 0 ) then
     ( select outrocampo from asterico ) /* não pode retornar mais de um registro esse subselect */ 
else
     ( round(sum((Caixa_9L / 1000)),1)  = 0 )
end as total from gin
```

Comment: Você referenciou no from só a tabela gin, a tabela asterisco não precisa? Quando eu rodo aqui, ele me diz que gin.asterico não existe.

Comment: Amigo, testei o código com algumas adaptações e esta ocorrendo o seguinte: Quando o campo Caixa_9l tem um valor registrado como zero, a query não acrescenta * mas 0.0, quando o campo Caixa_9l contem pelo menos 1 (uma unidade), ele coloca o *. O que pode ser isso?

Comment: `select 
marca,
case 
 gin.Caixa_9L when (round(sum(caixa_9l/1000),1)= 0) then (select asterisco.asterisco from asterisco)
else
 (round(sum((Caixa_9L/1000)),1))
end
as valor
from gin
where sales_channel = 'duty paid' or sales_channel = 'travel retail'
group by marca` Minha query ficou assim.